# docker, mount container folder to host

Tags: mount, docker

I need mount container's folder to host with all content from container.

In the container, there is this folder and there are a lot of files.

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1
```

On my host, I have this empty folder.

```
/opt/oracle/ohome
```

I need mount folder `/u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1` from container to host folder `/opt/oracle/ohome`, with all his content.

I need use files from container on host.

I tried this (and with source/target path changing too).

```
docker run -d -p 1521:1521 --shm-size=3g --name oracle -v /opt/oracle/ohome:/u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1 IMAGE
```

I tried with `bind` too, but no success, folder is empty in every case.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I have generally found it easier to go the other way around: share a directory on the host with the Docker container. This allows for multiple containers to use the same source directory (if that's something you need in the future) 

Comment: Does Docker have Permission to write to /opt/ ?

Comment: @EODCraftStaff Yes, all permissions are allowed. About mount from host to container, I know about it, but it is not good way for this case, but thanks matigo.